# auto-py-to-exe: Can't run exe created with windows 7 on windows 10 computer

Tags: python, tkinter

I created an .exe file using auto-py-to-exe in windows 7 system and it doesn't work in windows 10 computer. How can I make this exe so generic hence should be executable to other windows version as well, specifically in windows 7 & 10.

Comment: auto-py-to-exe isn't py2exe. Sounds like a bug in auto-py-to-exe so I suggest you contact the author or read his blog.

Comment: what  happens exactly ? any error message ?

Comment: It shows "fatal error detected, couldn't start xyz.exe", no specific wanring. Same exe works perfectly fine in windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must use windows 10 for converting py to *.exe as somehow windows 7 converted file does not work in windows 10, whereas the reverse is not the case.